# Mahapps title bar change color when application lost focus

Tags: wpf, titlebar, mahapps.metro

I define Title bar color:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow
...

WindowTitleBrush="Red"
```

But when the application lost focus this color always changed into `Gray`, is it possible to stop it ?

Comment: The window is theme-aware, so to stop it you can simply customize the title bar. Though there may be some other way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the property **NonActiveWindowTitleBrush** on the Metro Window. This is assuming that you are using a newer version of MahappsMetro.

Answer (score 0):

**Its Working** on Latest Version also

```
<Controls:MetroWindow...
.
.
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
WindowTitleBrush="Red"
```